# Como manter os dados já preenchidos no <input> após submeter um formulário?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou utilizando a linguagem PHP e o Framework Laravel 5.
Na validação do formulário, se contém algum campo em branco ou com tamanhos de caracteres não aceitos, ao clicar em salvar o sistema mostra a mensagem de validação, porém os campos que estavam preenchidos ficam em branco. Como manter os dados no formulário após clicar em salvar quando algum campo estiver incorreto? Código abaixo do formulário para cadastrar um produto.

**ProdutoController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\ProdutoRequest;
use App\Categoria;
use App\Produto;

class ProdutoController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('produto', array('categorias' => Categoria::all(),
                                     'produtos' => Produto::all()));
    }

    public function enviar(ProdutoRequest $request){
        $produto = new Produto();
        $produto->nome = $request->get('nome');
        $produto->preco = $request->get('preco');
        $produto->descricao = $request->get('descricao');
        $produto->categoria_id = $request->get('categoria');
        $produto->save();
        return redirect('/produtos');
    }

    public function detalhe($id) {
        $produto = Produto::find($id);
        return view('produto_detalhe', array('produto' => $produto));
    }

    public function formEditar($id){
        $produto = Produto::find($id);
        $categorias = Categoria::all();
        return view('produto_editar', array('produto' => $produto, 'categorias' => $categorias));
    }

    public function editar(ProdutoRequest $request){
        $produto = Produto::find($request->get('id'));
        $produto->nome = $request->get('nome');
        $produto->preco = $request->get('preco');
        $produto->descricao = $request->get('descricao');
        $produto->categoria_id = $request->get('categoria');
        $produto->save();
        return redirect('/produtos');
    }

    public function excluir($id){
        Produto::destroy($id);
        return redirect('/produtos');
    }
}
```

**ProdutoRequest.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class ProdutoRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nome' => 'min:3|max:100|required',
            'preco' => 'required',
            'descricao' => 'min:3|max:255|required',
            'categoria_id' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return[
            'nome.required' => 'Preencha o nome',
            'nome.min' => 'O nome deve ter no mínimo 3 caracteres',
            'nome.max' => 'O nome deve ter no máximo 100 caracteres',
            'preco.required' => 'Preencha o preço',
            'descricao.required' => 'Preencha a descrição',
            'descricao.min' => 'A descrição deve ter no mínimo 3 caracteres',
            'descricao.max' => 'A descrição deve ter no máximo 255 caracteres',
            'categoria_id.required' => 'Escolha uma categoria',
        ];
    }
}
```

**produto.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Produtos</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Produtos</h1>
        </div>

    @if(count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <form action="/produtos" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" id="nome">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Preço</label>
                    <input type="text" name="preco" class="form-control" id="preco">
                </div>              
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Descrição</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="descricao" id="descricao"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Categoria</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="categoria" id="categoria">
                        <option value="null">Selecione uma categoria</option>
                        @foreach($categorias as $row)
                        <option value="{{ $row->id }}">
                            {{ $row->nome }}
                        </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Salvar">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Preço</th>                        
                        <th>Categoria</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($produtos as $row)
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{{ $row->id }}</th>
                            <td>{{ $row->nome }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $row->preco }}</td>                         
                            <td>{{ $row->categoria->nome }}</td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-warning" href="/produtos/{{ $row->id }}/editar">Editar</a></td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-excluir" value="{{ $row->id }}">Excluir</button></td>                         
                            <td><a href="/produtos/{{ $row->id }}">Ver mais</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/scriptsProduto.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No meu caso isso não serviu, então criei uma classe que salva em seus atributos os dados da requisição, depois no metodo eu retorno a instancia desta classe para a view e exibo os dados nos inputs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Utilize o `helper` [old](http://www.laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-old), exemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="setor" value="{{old('setor')}}">
```

Em `value` coloque `old` entre parênteses o mesmo nome da tag que nesse caso é setor. Se houver validação e retornar será carregado o último valor digitado.

Em *textarea* ficaria assim:

```
<textarea name="texto">{{old('texto')}}</textarea>
```

Em `select` assim:

```
<label>Categoria</label>
<select class="form-control" name="categoria" id="categoria">
    <option value="null">Selecione uma categoria</option>
    @foreach($categorias as $row)
    <option @if(old('categoria')==$row->id) {{'selected="selected"'}} @endif value="{{ $row->id }}">
       {{ $row->nome }}
    </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Para seus estudos e próximos formulários *html* utilize esse pacote ele vai te ajudar principalmente nos `select`: [laravelcollective/html](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html).

Comment: Muito obrigada, deu certo!

Comment: Por nada @GrazianeTavares

Comment: Você sabe me dizer como fazer isso no textarea e no select option?

Comment: @GrazianeTavares no `textarea` é daquela forma, e no `select` tem que conferir item a item para ver se o id bate. Dá uma olhada teste e me de um feedback.

Comment: No textarea e no select option não funciona daquela forma e eu só tenho uma option pois os valores vem direto do banco de dados. Dê uma olhada na minha pergunta se puder   http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131264/como-manter-os-dados-j%C3%A1-preenchidos-no-textarea-e-no-select-option-ap%C3%B3s-submeter

Comment: @graziane funciona dessa forma talvez existe algo não condizente no seu código. Olha a minha edição...

Comment: o textarea deu certo mas o select infelizmente não

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40508/discussion-between-joao-and-graziane-tavares).

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="chosen" name="id_cidade" >
<option>Selecione</option>
@foreach ($cidade as $c)
    <option @if(old('id_cidade') == $c->id) selected @endif value="{{$c->id}}">{{$c->nome}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: De onde surgiu esse `id_cidade`? A pergunta se refere a um cadastro de produtos e não de endereços. Leia [answer]. Qualquer dúvida faça o nosso [tour].