# Como manter os dados já preenchidos no textarea e no select option após submeter um formulário?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou utilizando a linguagem PHP e o Framework Laravel 5. Na validação do formulário, se contém algum campo em branco ou com tamanhos de caracteres não aceitos, ao clicar em salvar o sistema mostra a mensagem de validação, porém os campos do textarea e do select option que estavam preenchidos ficam em branco. Como manter esses tipos de dados no formulário após clicar em salvar quando algum campo estiver incorreto?

Código do textarea:

```
    <textarea class="form-control" name="descricao" id="descricao"></textarea>
```

O meu select só tem uma option pois pega os valores direto do banco de dados.
Código do select option:

```
    <select class="form-control" name="categoria" id="categoria">           
        <option value="null"> Selecione uma categoria </option>
            @foreach($categorias as $row)
                <option value="{{ $row->id }}"
                    {{ $row->nome }}
                </option>
            @endforeach
    </select>
```

Comment: Graziane seja bem vinda ao Stack Overflow, por favor não duplique as perguntas sem necessidade. Ao que me parece a resposta do João lhe resolve tanto problemas com inputs, quanto selects e textareas, recomendo. Agora se o problema é outro poderia tentar explicar?

Comment: A entendi o que ocorreu, fez uma pergunta sobre input depois fez uma pergunta sobre textarea e select, todavia neste como o João respondeu sobre as 3 situações lá marcar ambas como duplicata [e apenas pra juntar o conteudo, não é uma penalidade =)

Answer (score 3):

Você deve usar a função `old`. Ela é responsável por trazer dos dados da sumissão anterior guardados num Session Flash.

Então, você pode simplesmente fazer assim:

```
 <input type="text" name="nome" value="{{ old('name') }} />
 <textarea name="texto">{{ old('texto') }}</textarea>
```

Porém, eu sugiro que você instale a biblioteca HTMLBuilder do Laravel Collective. Isso facilitará na criação dos inputs, textareas ou selects.

Exemplo:

```
{!! 
    Form::select('item_id', $itens, old('item_id'), ['class' => 'form-control']) 
!!}

{!!
   Form::textarea('texto', old('texto'))
!!}
```

Instruções para instalação do [Laravel Collective - HTML e Form Builder](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html)

Comment: tem ainda no controller de `redirect()->back()->withInput()`, ou não é necessário?

Comment: @Miguel depende. Se ela estiver usando o Request criado pela comando `php artisan make:request NomeDoRequest`, não precisa. o Laravel já faz automático

Comment: Haa não sabia, obgado @Wallace

Comment: A observação do @Miguel é bem pertinente. Nem sempre é necessário criar um FormRequest para o resource.